# Unknown TypeError : Cannot read property "search" of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying a basic search operation using the Youtube Data API v3.When I click on any of the buttons a string is passed to `searchyoutube` function.I want this string to be the search query.

Here's the JS named as app.js:

```
"use strict";
var query;
function searchyoutube (query){

var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
     part: 'snippet',
     type: 'video',
     q: query
});
console.log(query);

request.execute(function(response){
    console.log("Whatever");
});
}

function init()
{
    gapi.client.setApiKey("API KEY");
    gapi.client.load("youtube","v3",function(){
    //api ready
});
}
```

Here's the HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yy.css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<title>Title</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=init"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <h3>Header</h3>
    <h5>Random Header</h5>

    <form method="post">
    <ul class="youtube-categories" id="youtube-category">
        <li><button onClick ="searchyoutube('music')">Music</li>
        <li><button onClick ="searchyoutube('sports')">Sports</li>
        <li><button onClick ="searchyoutube('gaming')">Gaming</li>
        <li><button onClick ="searchyoutube('movies')">Movies</li>
        <li><button onClick ="searchyoutube('tv shows')">TV Shows</li>
        <li><button onClick ="searchyoutube('news')">News</li>
        <li><button onClick ="searchyoutube('live')">Live</li>
    </ul>
    </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I am new to JS so if i have made any noobish errors do let me know!

Comment: You didn't close your `button` tags. Also, having the `form` element isn't necessary for what you're doing.

Comment: You know you need a client ID, and to authenticate first ?

Comment: @J.Titus I tried closing the button tag.Doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would remove the inline javascript and use a delegated click event created in the `init` callback. The issue is likely due to timing, this route avoids that problem. Also, since all of the `<li>`'s text are the search terms, you can just use that to get what should be searched. So:

```
<ul class="youtube-categories" id="youtube-category">
  <li>Music</li>
  <li>Sports</li>
  <li>Gaming</li>
  <li>Movies</li>
  <li>TV Shows</li>
  <li>News</li>
  <li>Live</li>
</ul>
```

And updated javascript:

```
function init() {
  gapi.client.setApiKey("API KEY");
  gapi.client.load("youtube","v3",function(){
    document.querySelector('#youtube-category').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      // it's an <li> tag, get the text and search with it
      if(event.target.tagName === 'LI') {
        var searchTerm = event.target.textContent.toLowerCase();
        var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
             part: 'snippet',
             type: 'video',
             q: searchTerm
        });
        console.log(searchTerm);

        request.execute(function(response){
          console.log(response);
        });
      }
    }, false);
  });
}
```

Codepen example: http://jsbin.com/bezawasuta/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks mate! Worked like a charm!

Comment: Hey, I tried putting a button tag inside the li, and change `event.target.tagName === 'BUTTON'` and then changed `event.target.textContent.toLowerCase()` to `event.target.value()`,but didn't work.Is there anything else I need to change.Thanks!

Comment: No problem, i did it.Thanks anyway!